# How to get username from Django Rest Framework JWT token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am using Django Rest Framework and i've included a 3rd party package called [REST framework JWT Auth](http://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#usage). It returns a token when you send a username/password to a certain route. Then the token is needed for permission to certain routes. However, how do I get the username from the token? I've looked all through the package documentation and went through StackOverflow. It is a JSON Web Token and I am assuming there is a method like `username = decode_token(token)` but I haven't found such a method.

Comment: You have user object in request. Or you are not doing this in view?

Comment: I am doing this in view but I am new to Django so I don't fully understand how it works. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Add your view code

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basically you could do this

```
username = request.user.username
```

Comment: Seriously ? @sardorbek Why did you edit my code. I am using Camel Case type of coding. Is it really necessary to code with _ ?. There was no need.

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi read pep8 guidlines https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/. It is convention for python community

Comment: Yeah,I agree with that. But was is really necessary ? There are much better things to do than this.

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi You are answering question of beginner python developer. It is necessary to write answer which complies with python guidlines, because he will copy and paste your code and he will think that this kind of coding style is ok, which is not for our community.

Comment: Okay Sardorbek. Duly noted (no pun intended). Will keep this in mind from next time.

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi thank you) I just want StackOverflow to be as good as possible.

Comment: Hello Sardorbek. Can you tell where to use this in your DRF Code ? In View? Serializers ? Thanks.

Comment: @Addict this can be used everywhere, where `request` object is passed, but usually this is done in a view

Answer (score 12):

For me, this worked as [RestFrameworkJWT](https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-jwt/) is no longer maintained.
So I used the `rest_framework_simplejwt` package.

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.backends import TokenBackend
token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', " ").split(' ')[1]
data = {'token': token}
   try:
      valid_data = TokenBackend(algorithm='HS256').decode(token,verify=True)
      user = valid_data['user']
      request.user = user
   except ValidationError as v:
      print("validation error", v)
```

Comment: `verifty=False` - Disabling token verification is insecure, don't do this.

Comment: Editing the ans as suggested. @validname

Answer (score 11):

For me with Django (2.0.1), djangorestframework (3.7.7), djangorestframework-jwt (1.11.0).

I had to do following to get my use back user from token:

```
        token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', " ").split(' ')[1]
        print(token)
        data = {'token': token}
        try:
            valid_data = VerifyJSONWebTokenSerializer().validate(data)
            user = valid_data['user']
            request.user = user
        except ValidationError as v:
            print("validation error", v)
```

Or you can write a middleware that would set user based on their token.

Comment: I'm getting errors can you please share ur entire middleware file

Comment: Sorry, this is not what the user has asked for. But you can visit the link, it has entire middleware.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using djangorestframework_simplejwt, to get user object from JWT Token you need to do the following :

```
token = AccessToken(access_token)
user_id = token.payload['user_id']
user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
```

This works well !!