# Accessing logged in user name inside django middleware

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-middleware

I am trying to access `request.user.username` inside following django middleware:

```
class MyMiddleware():
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        user_id = request.user.username
        # ...
```

I ensured that `MyMiddleware` appears after `SessionMiddleware` and `AuthenticationMiddleware` in the `settngs.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    # ...
    `my_app.my_py_file.MyMiddleware`
)
```

But still the `request.user.username` turns out to be an empty string.

**Q1.** Why is it so?

I also tried adding `@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication,])`:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication # <--
from rest_framework.decorators import authentication_classes # <--

@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication,]) # <--
class MyMiddleware():
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        user_id = request.user.username
        # ...
```

But no help.

I also tried making class `APIView` (though it looks stupid as middleware is not a REST API):

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication # <--
from rest_framework.views import APIView # <--

class MyMiddleware(APIView): # <-- 
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication] # <--
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        user_id = request.user.username
        # ...
```

Still, it did not work.

Then I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57142064/6357916). It says:

> If you use simple_jwt, it's not possible to directly use request.user in a middleware because authentication mechanism works in view function. So you should manually authenticate inside the middleware and then you can use request.user to get whatever data from the user model.

It makes use of `rest_framework_simplejwt` which does not seem to be the part of django framework and needs to be installed explicitly.

The only way I am able to access `username` in my middleware is using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26246463/6357916). I modified my middleware as follows:

```
from re import sub
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

class MyMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response


    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        user_id = request.user.username

        if not user_id: 
            user_id = self.getUsername(request)
        
        # ...
    
    def getUsername(self, request):
        header_token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', None)
        if header_token is not None:
            try:
                token = sub('Token ', '', header_token)
                token_obj = Token.objects.get(key = token)
            except Token.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        return token_obj.user.username
```

**Q2.** Is this the only and correct way to access username inside middleware without installing third party libraries?

**Update**

Below is my `CustomUser` class and possibly related method `create_custom_user()`:

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # there are some application specific fields    

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
@debugger_queries
def create_custom_user(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    if kwargs['created']:  # create
        CustomUser.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

Comment: It is strange that it returns an empty string and not just an `AttributeError`. Did you use a custom user model?

Comment: Hold on with simple_jwt and Token. If you user is authenticated via session you don't have any of that. First, examine other user attributes. Instance of which class is user inside your middleware, if it's not AnonymousUser what is it id, email and other stuff.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how can I exactly tell if I have custom user. I just did quick search in vscode. The codebase has a lot of `request.user` access. Also there is `CustomUser(models.Model)` class.

Comment: @AlexandrZayets I tried debugging it. I tried printing `request.user` inside middleware in vscode debug console. It prints `<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7f882ead3f60>>`. (Also check my previous reply to @WilliemVanOnsem) Also can user name returned by `getUsername()` be incorrect?

Comment: @MsA: please share the `CustomUser` class and look for the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in the settings.

Comment: There is barely anything in that class. But I found one method `create_custom_user()`, though I didnt found where its called. Added both at the end of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to you answer here [Accessing logged in user name inside django middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76280108/accessing-logged-in-user-name-inside-django-middleware/76323117#comment134517698_76280108) -
`AnonymousUser` in the request user mean that at the moment when you checking it user is not authenticated. You can check code for anonymous user here - https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L417 . There's indeed an empty string for username.

I assume you are using django rest framework, so i answer based on that

Depending on which auth classes(https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme) you are using for rest framework authentication may go in different ways.
For `rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication` rest framework will get user from request. In that case `AuthenticationMiddleware` will assign correct user to request object and drf will have access.

For other auth types from drf such as `TokenAuthenticaton` session will not contain any info about user, because user will be authenticated via token passed in http header. In such cases you will not be able to access user in the middleware before auth class did it's job.

So possible solutions for you is either authenticate user manually with in middleware using your auth class like

```
user, token = TokenAuthentication().authenticate(request)
```

but be careful with that, because middleware will be applied for all requests, so you have to figure out how to not django admin or just regular pages if you use some

Alternatively you can place your logic somewhere else and not use middleware, depending on what you want to achive